# POST request with body and zipped data

Tags: rest, file, upload

I want to send a zip (.txt) file in POST request along with some JSON parameter in the request. 
What should be a sample request and header for the post request. 
Is adding varibales in POST URL is correct approach?
For Example : POST example.com/v1/name/{name}/Phone/{phone}/date/{date}/upload

[test.txt]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the file to a `byte` array and add it as a request body parameter to your request. Using `RestSharp` for .NET, here's how I added a file to my request:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/someEndpoint", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain"); // optional: depends on API
request.AddHeader("File-Name", fileName); // optional: depends on API

// add the file here. you need to provide the absolute path to it
request.AddParameter("text/plain", File.ReadAllBytes(absolutePathToYourFile), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Note: I used `Content-Type: text/plain` based on your comment about using a `.txt` file. However, if your file extension is `.zip`, you will want to use `application/zip` as your `Content-Type` parameter.